# High latency when sending events to Azure Event Hub

Tags: performance, azure-eventhub

I have an API which take a json object and forward it to Azure Event Hub. The API running .NET Core 3.1, with EventHub SDK 3.0, it also have Application Insight configured to collect dependency telemetry, including Event Hub.

Using the following kusto query in Application Insight, I've found that there are some call to Event Hub which have really high latency (highest is 60 second, on average it fall around 3-7 seconds).

```
dependencies 
| where timestamp > now()-7d
| where type == "Azure Event Hubs" and duration > 3000 
| order by duration desc
```

Also it is worth noting that it return 890 results, out of 4.6 million Azure Event Hubs dependency result

I've check Event Hub metrics blade on Azure Portal, with average (in 1 minute time granularity) incoming/outgoing request way below the throughput unit (I have 2 event hubs in a EH namespace, 1 TU, autoscale to 20 max), which is around 50-100 message per second, bytes around 100kB, both incoming and outgoing. 0 throttled requests, 1-2 server/user errors from time to time

There are spike but it does not exceed throughput limit, and the slow dependency timestamp also don't match these spike

I also increased throughput unit to 2 manually, and it does not change anything

My question is:

1. Is it normal to have extremely high latency to Event Hub sometimes? Or it is acceptable if it only in small amount?
2. Codewise, only use 1 EventHubClient instance to send all the request, it is a bad practice or should I used something else like a client pool?
3. I also have a support engineer told me during a timestamp where I have high latency in Application Insight, the Event Hub log does not seem to have such high latency (322ms max), without going into details, it is possible for Application Insight to produce wrong performance telemetry?

Comment: Regarding #2 it is best practices to reuse the client

Comment: Regarding #3 app insights measures the total time, including the time it takes to reach the endpoint. The event hub log shows the processing time of the request itself. The latency is the different of those two. Might be a slow connection. Is the api hosted in the same region as the event hub?

Comment: The api is hosted in the same region as the event hub. So having such network latency is kinda weird

Comment: How do you measure the latency? Can you contain latency measurement to EH service only?

Comment: I didn't measure the latency, I just include Application Insight into our apps and it automatically collect EventHub (and others) dependencies with the duration/latency.